# Returning Devise errors based on conditions with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I post a `session` to rails/devise, I either get response with the `user` data, or i get a bland error message. How can I send back custom messages based on what goes wrong with creating if the session?

current code:

```
class V1::SessionsController < ApiBaseController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def create
      email = params[:user] && params[:user][:email]
      username = params[:user] && params[:user][:username]

      @user = User.where(email: email).first if email
      @user = User.where(username: username).first if username

      if @user&.valid_password?(params[:user] && params[:user][:password])

       @user.update_user_login_timestamp
       respond_to do |format|
         format.json { render '/users/show', status: :ok }
       end
       else
         render json: {success: false, message: "no good"}, status: 500
       end
     end

   private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :username)
  end

end
```

What I'd like to do:

```
if username_found_but_password_doesnt_match
   render json: {error: "bad password"} status: 500
 elsif username_not_found
   render json: {error: "doesnt exist"} status: 500
end
```

Comment: What about `username_found_but_password_not_found`?

Comment: is that an actual devise method??

Comment: No, it isn't. Is `username_found_but_password_doesnt_match` a real method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the `create` action as:

```
def create
  email = params[:user] && params[:user][:email]
  username = params[:user] && params[:user][:username]
  @user = User.where(email: email).first if email
  @user = User.where(username: username).first if username

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.blank?
      format.json { render json: {error: "doesnt exist"}, status: 404 }
    elsif @user.valid_password?(params[:user] && params[:user][:password])
      @user.update_user_login_timestamp
      format.json { render '/users/show', status: :ok }
    else
      format.json { render json: {error: "bad password"}, status: 422 }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: so if @user.blank? would be nil if username DNE, correct?